# asp.net mvc routing - Multiple Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've just started MVC and I can pass through an ID to a page but can't seem to get my routing to work with two parameters. Does anyone have any ideas why?

Here is my code:

**Global:**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           "Default", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
       ); 




    routes.MapRoute(
    "EditVoucher",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{userid}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "EditVoucher", id = "", userid = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );     


**My controller:**  

[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult EditVoucher(int ID, int UserID)
 {
}


**my link:**

 @Html.ActionLink("[Edit]", "EditVoucher", new { Controller = "Admin", id = item.ID, userid = 2 })  



this passes through the values fine but I end up with this sort of URL:

**/Admin/EditVoucher/2?userid=2**

thanks
```

Comment: How do you end up with that URL?

Comment: Huh? What are you asking about? What did that URL come from?

Comment: I have added it: here it is again: @Html.ActionLink("[Edit]", "EditVoucher", new { Controller = "Admin", id = item.ID, userid = 2 })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActionLink` will use the first route that can satisfy your parameters.

Since the first (default) route also satisfies your parameters, you need to put the custom route first.

Comment: I already tried that and the following error when starting the site up: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditVoucher(Int32, Int32)' in 'Vouchers.Admin.UI.Controllers.AdminController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: My mistake mate, I tried it again but added the name of the action and controller, thanks very much!